# Can anyone help identify this character 僮?

Tags: meaning, words, usage, nuances, kanji

I found this character on a website and the only associated meaning was "child, servant." Can anyone elaborate on when it may be used and why?

Comment: could you copy/paste the sentence or paragraph you found it in, please?

Answer (score 2):

僮 is a very rare *kanji* which does not belong to the list of 常用漢字 *jōyō kanji*.

According to 新漢和大辞典, it has several meanings

> 1. 召使。男の奴隷。また、雑用をする子者【こもの】。［同］童。［類］豎・僕・奴。
> 2. 何も知らない子ども。また、無知な者。［同］童。
> 3. 「僮僮【ドウドウ】」とは、見えなくするほど、上からおおいかぶさるさま。
> 4. 中国の西南部、広西[壮]【チワン】族自治区、広東【カントン】・雲南省あたりに住むタイ系の先住民。チワン族。▽もと「⺨+童」と書いたが、のち、「僮」に改め、現在では、「壮」と書く。

(I didn't list the examples.)

大辞林 lists 僮 as a valid (but of course uncommon) replacement for 童 in words like 童僕【どうぼく】, 家童【かどう】, 侍童【じどう】 which all refer to some type of (young) servant.